# AWS - Python BOTO3 resource groups tagging api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get a list of all my AWS Tagged Ressources using this peace of code:

```
import boto3
import jsbeautifier

session = boto3.Session()
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
res=client.get_resources(
   ResourceTypeFilters=[
       #first try: 'ec2:instance'
       #second try: elasticloadbalancing:loadbalancer
       #third try: 's3:bucket' 
]
)
```

while the first and second try work well, the third isn't working. The error code is:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the GetResources operation: productName=s3 has no resourceType

Does anyone know the list of aws Services supported by 'ResourceTypeFilters' or has a link ?
A lot of websites describe how to use resourcegroupstaggingapi but I couldn't find a list of available services.

Comment: Believe you can simply use `s3`.

Comment: S3 is in the supported service list for resource group.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/supported-services.html